# Inner Product of a Symplectic Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm going through appendix 3 of Lax's Linear Algebra book, and I'm a bit confused about the concept of the symplectic matrix.  From what I understand, we are looking for a matrix $A$ which fulfills $(x,Ay)=-(Ay,x)$, where he further specifies to the matrix
\begin{equation}
J=\begin{pmatrix}
O & I\\
-I & O
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
written in block notation.  The first point of confusion is whether it is an $O$ representing an orthogonal matrix, or a zero.

My second issue is the exercise which I'm trying to work through, which is to show that any real $2n\times 2n$ anti-self-adjoint matrix $A$ can be written in the form
\begin{equation}
A=FJF^T
\end{equation}
since my approach has been to essentially define
$$F^Tx=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}$$
then carry out the inner product with $J$ to try and find some tautology to show that $A$ can be written in that form.  However, this approach requires me to know for certain whether the element in $J$ is an $O$ or a zero.  I'm also not entirely sure whether the alternating nature of the bilinear function is correct (since I think $(x,Ay)=-(y,Ax)$ would also fit the definition, but from what I've seen online it seems that the form I have written out is the correct way).  Any explanation would be appreciated, but I'd still like to give working out the exercise a shot so ideally not a full answer.

Comment: The two diagonal sub-blocks $O$ in $J$ are zero. And no, you are not looking for an $A$ such that $(x,Ay)=-(y,Ax)$. The nonsingular skew-symmetric matrix $A$ is given. What you are supposed to study are the matrices $L$ that preserve the the alternating bilinear form $(x,Ay)$. That is, you are going to study those $L$ such that $(x,Ay)=(Lx,ALy)$. This means $A=L^TAL$. ...

Comment: ...If one can prove that $A^T=FJF^T$ for some matrix $F$, the equation $A=L^TAL$ can be rewritten as $J=S^TJS$ by the change of variable $S=(F^{-1}L^TF)^T$. This is why Lax wrote that “it suffices to specialize to $A=J$”.